# Python:In-lining code inside time-critical loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading a python blog to understand how to optimise the code.
While reading I encounter this statement:

> Function call overhead is large compared to other instructions.
>   Accordingly, it is sometimes worth in-lining code inside time-critical
>   loops.

**What does in-lining code mean**? Could anyone explain it with the help of an example?

[Blog: Optimise python program](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed)

Answer (score 2):

This just means that you can get small improvements by removing function calls, and just putting the code directly in the loop. Consider the following benchmarks:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('foo()', '''
... def foo():
...     for i in range(1,1000):
...         bar(i)
... def bar(x): return x + 42 / (x*3)
... ''', number=100)
0.026873827097006142
>>> timeit.timeit('foo()', '''
... def foo():
...     for i in range(1,1000):
...         i + 42 / (i*3)
... ''', number=100)
0.016869006911292672
```

However, the downside of this is less encapsulation and modularity in your program.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it's trying to say sometimes function call is costly, and inline code is better. For example:

```
def addnum(x,y):
    return x+y

lis = [1,2,3,4]
result = 0
for i in lis:
    result = addnum(result, i)
```

Above code called the function many times. You could avoid that:

```
lis = [1,2,3,4]
result = 0
for i in lis:
    result = result + i
```